# JQuery/HTML/CSS how can i implement jcarousel slider in a thick box pop page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

i am trying to implement A **J CAROUSEL SLIDER** in a popup opened via thick box.

have tried a lot but still not got any success. its working in HTML while calling direct but while calling via popup it doesn't work.

Can any body help me out of this, even a small help also will be appreciated.

Comment: so you selected the carousel slider and it is working fine in the html page right? and it is not working in the popup box is this is your question?

Comment: what have you done to get the popup is there any plugin there.. Try to post your code

Comment: yes using thickbox for popup and carousel for slider

Answer (score 0):

You should load the plugin and jquery separately in that popup.. A popup is a new page and all the js and css files should be loaded also there

So your popup code should be like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to/css.css" />
    <script src="path-to/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="path-to/jQuery.jCarousel.js"></script>
    <script>
      // jCarousel init
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use absolute paths for css and js so if you are using the paths like the example above `path-to/jQuery.js` change it with `/website-root/path-to/jQUery.js`. Note the appearance of `/`